# UserControl embeding free XAML content

Tags: winrt-xaml

I would like to create a User Control which can embed free content.

I created a Dependency property for the content :

```
public sealed partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
{

    public Border MyProperty
    {
        get { return (Border)GetValue(MyPropertyProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MyPropertyProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyPropertyProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MyProperty", typeof(Border), typeof(VisitList), new PropertyMetadata(new Border() { Height=300, Width=300 }));

...
}
```

So In my MainPage.xaml, I can use it with following code :

```
 <MyUserControl>
            <MyUserControl.MyProperty>
                <Border x:Name="MyContent" Width="60" Height="60" Background="Pink">
                    ... Whatever ...
                </Border>
            </MyUserControl.MyProperty>                
 </MyUserControl>
```

From this, I can't find what is the XAML syntax in the MyUserControl.xaml for declaring the placeholder that will be substituted by MyContent at runtime.
I tried with :

```
<UserControl ... >
....
    <Grid ...>

         <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding MyProperty}" />

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

But, it crashes with message :

```
An exception of type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in xXx.exe but was not handled in user code
WinRT information: Failed to create a 'Windows.UI.Xaml.DependencyProperty' from the text 'MyProperty'. [Line: 29 Position: 35]
```

(The Line: 29 Position:35 refers to  Content="{TemplateBinding MyProperty}")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're mixing Templated Controls and UserControls. It's a bit complicated, but basically, TemplateBindings work when they're apart of the ContentTemplate of the control, as opposed to the Content itself (which is what I believe is happening here, based on the xaml you have shown).

Try changing your bindings in this way:

```
<UserControl x:Name="RootControl" ...>
....
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding MyProperty, ElementName=RootControl}" />
....
</UserControl>
```

What this means is that you will need to have your UserControl implement INotifyPropertyChanged in case it needs to respond to changing `Content`.

Comment: What Nate says is good, but what I would also do is I would define your property as a `DataTemplate` type instead of `Border` and use `ContentControl.ContentTemplate` instead of `ContentControl.Content` to use it.

Comment: Thanks, Nate advice works great. And thanks to Filip, I can use any xaml code (instead of Border)